# jQuery Gallery will show locally on Firefox and Chrome but won't work online

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, gallery

I tested a jQuery-gallery locally in every browser available. Worked like a charm. However; when i upload everything to my server it won't load properly. Looked in the source but couldn't find the flaw.

Any ideas?

URL: http://www.pastisamsterdam.nl/proto/impressie.html

Comment: ``The requested URL /proto/Images/impressie/1.jpg was not found on this server.`` did you uploaded the images ? In javascript console you get ``Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your server, is your paths.
The folder `/proto/Images/impressie/` does not exist on your server, but `/proto/images/impressie/` is, this means you have a unix based system which is case-sensitive.

Change the images path to `/proto/images/impressie/` and your script should work.

Comment: Damn. Thanks! Kind of noobish. Well it's one character in a whole source so I don't feel too bad. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug for these kind of problems. Path (http://www.pastisamsterdam.nl/proto/Images/impressie) to your images is not valid, that's why they are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Images` to `images` and it will work. Because your server is case-sensitive, I think :)

Happy coding ^^

Answer (score 0):

Update the image src to link to the correct url, if you posted the actual path to the image, i can tell you the src for the image.